# how to enable intervlan between juniper core switch and Cisco catalyst 1000

Tags: cisco, juniper

i have a juniper 4600 core with 2300 Access switches in my VLAN, one of the 2300 failed and replaced with cisco 2300 in one VLAN, DHCP is assigning IP to clients and internet is working fine, the printer are not able to connect and i also can not manage the CISCO 1000 switches using management or VLAN IP. Any idea is appreciated

Comment: usually cisco has dedicated console ports for this case

Answer (score 0):

I have a Cisco Catalyst 1000. If you have configured a SVI management IP you can remotely connect to it. Otherwise, you'll need to use a console cable to connect. This is no different than any other Catalyst switch.